# How to detect if an instance of a superclass is a subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am downcasting a `UITableViewCell` to a custom subclass I have created, then assigning that to a `UITableViewCell` instance. Later I need to know if the downcast has occurred. Basically I need to know if the cell is an instance of the subclass even though it is now defined as an instance of the superclass.

`isKindOfClass` won't do the trick because that is only true when it is an instance of that class or an instance of a class that inherits from that class, neither of which are technically true, even though the cell actually is an instance of the class but just examining the passed in variable it's impossible to know that.

**How could one assign a subclass to a regular `UITableViewCell` variable and later know whether nor not it's an instance of the subclass?**

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
CustomCellClass *customCell = (CustomCellClass *)[super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell = customCell;
//...
if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCellClass class]]) {
    //this is never true but I need to run code here
}
return cell
```

Comment: "because that is only true when it is an instance of that class or an instance of a class that inherits from that class, neither of which are technically true, even though the cell actually is an instance of the class" - wait, what? it **is** and **is not** the instance of the subclass at the same time? that's impossible... it's hard to tell what your problem is.

Comment: What does the code look like where you create the cell?  Are you actually registering and dequeueing a `CustomCellClass`?  Or is your cast just wishful thinking?  See also `isMemberOfClass:` if you want a specific class.  See also `object_getClass()`.

Comment: No I don't dequeue a `CustomCellClass cell`. I am creating the cell in the provided code, indeed it appears to be wishful thinking even though it is 100% safe to "downcast" my `UITableViewCell` to my custom subclass. (I only do it conditionally hence the need to check later if that has occurred.) `isMemberOfClass` also returns `NO` in the provided code. I understand this seems odd but essentially the cell I need to return must strictly be of `CustomCellClass` if it is of that class, but I need to configure it as a regular `UITableViewCell`. I would cast the cell and return it in the comment.

Comment: "I need to know if the downcast has occurred" This is nonsense. A downcast does not "occur". It doesn't **do** anything. It's just a note to the compiler not to complain about a type mismatch. It has no effect at runtime. If `-isKindOfClass:`, `-isMemberOfClass:` and `-respondsToSelector:` are saying the object is not of the desired class or doesn't respond to the method, then the object is not (and never was) of the type you thought it was.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Either your object IS in the inheritance tree (is an instance) of `CustomCellClass`, or it's NOT. There are no in between states and there's no way to change that.

Now, it would help to show us your full code, so we can give you a better explanation, but here's a try:

Now, with inheritance, there are rules. One primary rule is that you can't 'downcast' an object. You can only 'upcast' it. If you create an NSObject, you can't cast.  it into a UIView. You can, however, cast a UIView into an NSObject.

So, for your code, you can't cast `cell` to be a `CustomCellClass` because cell isn't starting out as a CustomCellClass. Very easy change, really!

Edit:
if `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns a `CustomCellClass` object, then the following will work. But I don't recommend thinking about it as a "downcast." It is normally just called "casting".

What you want:

```
CustomCellClass *cell = (CustomCellClass *)[super tableView:tableView    cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCellClass class]]) {
    // This will be true because it was created as a CustomCellClass object.
}
return cell
```

Comment: You *can* downcast an object. In fact, you're doing it in your code sample.

Comment: If it starts out as CustomCellClass and you know it is a CustomCellClass, you can downcast to it.  However, if you create a UITableViewCell just casting it to a CustomCellClass does not make it a CustomCellClass.  It makes it something dangerous waiting to happen.

Comment: @AaronBrager My apologies, I left out what jeffamaphone said. I assumed that in my head, but forgot to list that as an assumption. Yes, if the object was initialized in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: as CustomCellClass, it can be downcast. I don't like the term downcasting because I think it's misleading. It's simply casting it back to what it initially started out as.

Comment: Right, but your answer uses the term "downcast" incorrectly. Casting objects (up or down) *never* changes the type of object.

Comment: @AaronBrager That would be my problem them. If casting never changes the type of the object, how does one detect if the cast has occurred when it has been assigned to a different variable which is its superclass?

Comment: @Joey Casts don't "occur". They're (basically) just hints for autocompleting code and avoiding compiler errors while you write your code. At run-time, all that matters is what your object actually is.

Comment: Is this your actual question? "My table view is pumping out `UITableViewCell`s. How do I get it to give me `CustomCellClass`s instead?"

Comment: @AaronBrager Thanks, that's not what I had thought. Hence what I want to obtain won't work at all. I wanted some way to 'convert' a `UITableViewCell` into a `CustomCellClass` cell without having to define it as such in the first place.

Comment: @Joey You can technically convert them using `object_setClass`, but there's probably an easier and safer way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @AaronBrager Wow, setClass did exactly what I needed! And I already was keeping a BOOL to determine whether or not the cell should be that custom subclass, so I simply changed the class when appropriate and it's working beautifully. Indeed it's probably not recommended but it works well.

Comment: @AaronBrager Want to add an answer to note a downcast really didn't occur and mention `object_setClass` to implement the desired setup so that I may accept it?

Comment: If `CustomCellClass` adds anything to `UITableViewCell` besides methods (like instance variables), then `object_setClass()` won't help. `object_setClass()` will change the method table but won't change the size of the object or what instance variables it has. Also, it doesn't retroactively change how the object was initialized or configured to that point, for example. Honestly, judging from what you've said, `object_setClass()` is over your head at this point in your understanding. Avoid the Objective-C runtime functions until you have a better grasp on the fundamentals.

Comment: @KenThomases The subclass only overrides the `setFrame` method.

Answer (score 1):

If the ultimate purpose of this is to use a function that is only available in the subclass then use:

If ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(mysubclassFunction)] {
// this cell is a subclass and responds to that function
}

Comment: That condition isn't true when the `cell` is a `UITableViewCell` variable, even when it was originally a `CustomCellClass`.

Comment: "If the cell is a UITableViewCell variable" - What do you mean?